# better way to determine MVC3 area of referrer from ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have an ajax call that gets a list of events for specific users, it works OK no problem with anything ajaxy. When I call it from the admin area of the app I want it to behave slightly differently but the only way I've found to determine if it's called from the admin area is to check the Referrer segments and see if the referring page is in the admin area.

Is there a different (more built in MVC) way to do this?

At moment the action called looks like

```
public ActionResult Events(string recorded, bool ongoing)
{
 if (this.Request.UrlReferrer.Segments.Contains("Administration/"))
           :
```

and works fine, it just looks a little hackety.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you calling the same controller across the application?  Can't you just create the same method in the Admin controller that makes the changes you want and then calls the original Events method?

Comment: @Rastapopulous Yes, same controller because it's called from a javascript/jQuery function, so it hits the root of the app, which works well - I had hoped that buried somewhere deep in MVC was a way (other than slicing up the referrer) to know what Area the request had come from.

Comment: You could change the routing so that requests for that function from the Administrator page are handled to a different method.  You'd probably still need to use your .Contains to change the logic at the routing level.  It might be more MVC-y, but it's basically the same thing you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url referrer is the only indication that you could use. But if this feels hacky to you, simply add some parameter to your AJAX call when calling from an area:

```
public ActionResult Events(string recorded, bool ongoing, bool isAdminAreaOrigin = false)
{
    if (isAdminAreaOrigin)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I think that might be even more hacky. At the moment the `if` is only referenced in one place; the controllers action. If I go with a parameter I'd need to indicate being in an area at the view level and there are multiple. On the other hand, this way would ensure that should someone add a view or controller called Administration my Referrer matching wouldn't get confused.

Answer (score 0):

`RouteData.DataTokens["area"]`

Comment: The RouteData only gives me info on the current controller, the one called from via ajax, what I'm looking for is the area for the current page the ajax is calling from.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that you were looking at the referrer. In that case what you've got is probably best.

Comment: No worries - I did look hard at what's normally available but I guess there's no reason for an ajax initiated controller action to know anything about the page that contains the ajax call and all I'm left with is standard HTTP stuff to determine the source of the ajax.